# How to include Variable in File Path (Python)

Tags: python

I am currently writing a small networkchat in Python3. I want to include a function to save the users history. Now my user class contains a variable for name and I want to save the history-file in a folder which has the name of the user as its name.

So for example it roughly looks like that:

```
import os
import os.path

class User:
    name = "exampleName"
    PATH = './exampleName/History.txt'

    def SaveHistory(self, message):
        isFileThere = os.path.exists(PATH)
        print(isFileThere)
```

So it is alwasy returning "false" until I create a folder called "exampleName".
Can anybody tell me how to get this working?
Thanks alot!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/in-python-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary

Answer (score 1):

if you use *relative paths* for file or directory names python will look for them (or create them) in your *current working directory* (the `$PWD` variable in bash).

if you want to have them relative to the current python file, you can use (python 3.4)

```
from pathlib import Path
HERE = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
PATH = HERE / 'exampleName/History.txt'

if PATH.exists():
    print('exists!')
```

or (python 2.7)

```
import os.path
HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PATH = os.path.join(HERE, 'exampleName/History.txt')

if os.path.exists(PATH):
    print('exists!')
```

if your `History.txt` file lives in the `exampleName` directory below your python script.