# Creating New Folder/Directory in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Want to create a new folder, getting an error.

Method:

```
def IDW_to_df(conn, quarter, file_name,sql_statement, *columns):
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_statement)
Dict = {}
for column in columns:            
    Dict[column]=[]
while 1:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    x = 0
    for column in columns:
        Dict[column].append(row[x])
        x += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
df.to_csv('H:/Q{0}/{1}.csv'.format(quarter,file_name))
return df
```

The method itself functions properly, just the folder creation throws the error. When called, I get the following error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:/Q4/FOO_IND.csv'
```

Comment: Check that you have the directory `H:/Q4`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, check if a directory exists and create it if necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/in-python-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary)

Comment: In your code there's no attempt to create directory at all...

Comment: Thought it created it automatically if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, had to create directory first.  Will probably add some checks in the future to ensure the "new" directory doesn't already exist.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
def IDW_to_df(conn, quarter, file_name,sql_statement, *columns):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_statement)
    Dict = {}
    for column in columns:            
        Dict[column]=[]
    while 1:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if not row:
            break
        x = 0
        for column in columns:
            Dict[column].append(row[x])
            x += 1
    df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
    os.makedirs('H:/Q{0}'.format(quarter))
    df.to_csv('H:/Q{0}/{1}.csv'.format(quarter,file_name))
    return df
```