# How Return EXIF tags using PyExifTool

Tags: python, exif

I am having trouble figuring out how to extract an EXIF tag from a raw photo using [PyExifTool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/). All I want to do is extract the date the photo was created and rename the project folder with that date. I've tried a variety of things I keep getting a series of errors ending with "ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded").

Like:

```
    import exiftool
    files = "CRW_1368.CRW"

    with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
        metadata = et.get_tag(DateTimeOriginal, files)

    print execute_json(metadata)
```

It's not clear to me how to properly set it up. I am relatively new to scripting.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question is not in accordance with StackOverflow's guidelines.  `Nothing seems to work` does not properly describe the problem.  What happens?  What error codes do you receive?  Since it is a salvageable question, i will not, at this time, vote to close it.  But do edit it quick because, otherwise, someone else will close this question down.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure that the tag exists.  In my test, there was no `DateTimeOriginal` tag, so I had to select a tag that was actually in my file.  I chose 'DateCreated'.  I got the error that `execute_json` wasn't defined.  When I changed it to `et.execute_json`, I was able to get your same error.  Since you're only pulling one tag, you should be able to just print it.  By a quick change of your print statement, I got the expected date/time.

```
import exiftool
import os, errno
files = file.jpg

with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    metadata = et.get_tag('DateCreated', files)
    print(metadata)
# or, (skipping those two lines) as per your actual question
    new_folder = et.get_tag('DateCreated', files)
    try:
        os.makedirs(new_folder)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

And in my case, with the print statement, got back the expected 
'2017:04:25 17:40:42' from my file.

For updated alternatives to directory checking/creating, see:
[How can I create a directory if it does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist)