# Constantly returning 'file not found' when trying to retreive .jpg EXIF data

Tags: python, python-3.x, exif, exiftool

I am trying to use PyExifTool to examine the EXIF data of given images. I am using an almost identical copy of what can be found in the [github support documents](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) and another [StackOverflow resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321518/how-return-exif-tags-using-pyexiftool).

This is what my code looks like:

```
import exiftool
import os, errno
files = ["/Users/username/Pictures/testimage.jpg"]

with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    metadata = et.get_tag('DateCreated', files)
    print(metadata)
```

I then receive quite the error message. As I am very new to coding I am struggling to troubleshoot this response.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 191, in __enter__
    self.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 170, in start
    self._process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'exiftool'
```

Presumably, the key piece of information here is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'exiftool'
```

Except that I don't really understand what I am being told? ExifTool is supposed to be a tool, I am not intentionally trying to access it as a file or directory.

I can be certain ExifTool is correctly installed because if in command line I run...

```
#bash:~

$ exiftool /Users/username/Pictures/testimage.jpg
```

...ExifTool returns all the Exif data for my test image including an in-tact 'Date Created' field. Incidentally, this also confirms that my path is correct.

---

**Edit 1:** Additional information as per the request of tripleee

(Excuse my ignorance if and when I give the wrong information)

**-** *How do I run the script?*
-> I just have that snippet of code in a .py document and then it runs in my idle shell?

**-** *Running `type -all exiftool` in Bash*

```
exiftool is /usr/local/bin/exiftool
exiftool is /usr/local/bin/exiftool
```

(yes it does give the same thing twice)

**-** *Running `print(os.environ['PATH'])` in IDLE*

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

---

**Edit 2:** Additional troubleshooting off the back of Tripleee's queries

**-** *Running `type -all exiftool` in Bash gave two paths.*

```
exiftool is /usr/local/bin/exiftool
exiftool is /usr/local/bin/exiftool
```

--> I used some code I found elsewhere to try and fix this.

```
PATH=$(printf "%s" "$PATH" | awk -v RS=':' '!a[$1]++ { if (NR > 1) printf RS; printf $1 }')
```

Now running `type -all exiftool` in Bash gives only...

```
exiftool is /usr/local/bin/exiftool
```

Until I open a new terminal window/tab, a which point the problem returns.

***-** *How do I run the script?**

Well now I open terminal and input `IDLE3` so that it is opened from prompt, not via the icon on my hotbar.

This gives a new error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    metadata = et.get_tag('Date Created', files)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 325, in get_tag
    return self.get_tag_batch(tag, [filename])[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 312, in get_tag_batch
    data = self.get_tags_batch([tag], filenames)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 291, in get_tags_batch
    return self.execute_json(*params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 252, in execute_json
    return json.loads(self.execute(b"-j", *params).decode("utf-8"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/exiftool.py", line 108, in fsencode
    return filename.encode(encoding, errors)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

The key difference being it ends:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

---

**Edit 3:** Additional troubleshooting off the back of Tripleee's queries

**-** *Discovered I had added nano .bash_profile to the end of my .bash_profile.*

--> This has been removed

**-** *Running `print(os.environ['PATH'])` in IDLE but now from prompt using `IDLE3`*

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/fsl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Probably your Python script has a different `PATH` than you have at the prompt. Can you [edit] to clarify how exactly you run the script, and perhaps add the output of `type -all exiftool` at the Bash prompt, and ideally an indication of whether `print(os.environ['PATH'])` from your Python script (before the crash) includes the directory part of that result?

Comment: @tripleee I have added additional information to the bottom of my post. If you are able could you see if it is correct and whether it reveals anything to you?

Comment: Whether IDLE inherits your prompt's `PATH` will depend on whether you run IDLE from the prompt. Clearly you don't; I'm guessing you are double-clicking an icon somewhere. If you can fill in the blanks we might be able to tell you how to fix it properly. Quick and dirty - and hopefully obvious - workarounds would be to run IDLE from the shell prompt, or manually update the value of `os.environ['PATH']` at the IDLE prompt.

Comment: The duplicate output from `type` suggests that you have `/usr/local/bin` on your `PATH` multiple times. This is harmless (unless you need to optimize for microseconds) but can produce slightly confusing results like this. Propably you (or some tool you ran) edited your `.bash_profile` one time too many. If you are using Homebrew, I have noticed that it sometimes adds stuff there when it shouldn't.

Comment: Surely you ran `print` in Python, not in Bash?

Comment: @tripleee yes lol. Sorry about that. I am out now but that was definitely ran in python.

Comment: @Tripleee In response to your first comment, I run IDLE by clicking on a button which then opens it. I don't run it from my terminal, truthfully I'm not savvy enough to grasp any appreciable differences. Every time I open my terminal I end up in my .bash_profile (in Nano) and I have no idea how to resolve this. It's an ongoing issue that seems too trivial to pose on Stack. The duplicates are nothing to do with intentional optimisation, probably me trying to do something in the past. Running os.environ['Path'] returns /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219819/discussion-between-solebay-sharp-and-tripleee).

Comment: Sorry, not in a place where I can chat. Sounds like you have added `nano .bash_profile` to the end of your `.bash_profile`. This is a separate topic anyway; maybe post a separate question on [apple.se] or [unix.se] if you need more help.

Comment: @Tripleee, I understand, thank you for helping me this far and investing your time.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem also but the last entry on your `PATH` should be simply `/opt/X11/bin` without the final `~/.bash_profile` ... Though I'd be slightly surprised if you really have X11 binaries on a Mac. Does this directory even exist?

Comment: Good if your Awk snippet works around the acute problem but likely the root cause is that your `.bash_profile` is probably a royal mess. Cleaning it up is more of a general computing problem so again not suitable for Stack Overflow, but I really suggest you visit either of the sibling sites I linked above and ask a separate question with your full `.bash_profile` and probably some back story around how you ended up with that train wreck.

Comment: The new error is finally an actual bug in your code, `files` is a list but you are passing it to a function which expects a string, not a list. Either take out the square brackets in the assignment, or if you want to process more than one file, loop over them one by one like `for file in files: metadata = eg. get_tag('DateCreated', file)` etc.

Comment: Finally, did you misspell John Locke in your profile?

Comment: 1). I think I do have X11 binaries as I needed Xcode to run [FSL](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/). The installation of FSL did not go smoothly and was probably when I messed up my `.bash_profile`. 2). Thank you for your links, today's job is to ask help on a Unix/Linux forum so the issue is permanently resolved. 3). Thank you for fixing my code 4). Yes that is an ignoble misspelling of Locke's last name 5). If you want to provide a condensed answer to my problem I will mark it as correct (if the rep is important to you), if not I will do it (and credit you) once I fix `.bash_profile`.

Comment: To anyone who might have a similar problem, a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604764/duplicate-paths-that-i-cant-delete-possible-issues-with-bash-profile) has been opened on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) forum.