# dynamic directories in python

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder named "fp" wherein lies folders for each subject. Within each subjects folder lies further set of folders for subjects data named 000001, 000002 etc.

I can store the directory for the "fp" folder in a variable. And then I would like to create another variable with another directory for each subject.
 It is as if I want to create a variable subjects = "sub*" that means that all subjects folders begin with "sub"....

And then further on, define another directory in the same way for the data folder = subjects/'0000000*' meaning that all data folders within each participants folder begin with 7 zeros (or whatever). How can this be done?

I do not want to check if they exist or create if necessary. I want to go through each subject and each subjects datafolders to finally obtain information from the first file in the datafolder

in MATLAB this could be done like follows, I think:

```
   subjectPattern = 'sub*';  % name pattern
   rootDir = '...../fp'; 
   dirs = dir(fullfile(rootDir, subjectPattern));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a directory exists and create it if necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary)

Comment: I do not want to check if they exist or create if necessary. I want to go through each subject and each subjects datafolders to finally obtain information from the first file in the datafolder

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having trying to achieve your goal.

Comment: It seems to me like you want to `os.listdir` in the folder and then create a dict entry for each folder. As i'm not sure, I suggest you post a treeview of the folder structure and a data structure you'd like to receive.