# CMD Create a new folder but "The filename, directory, or volume syntax is incorrect"

Tags: python, cmd

I tried to use Python to run the following command lines. The first command line can always work, but the second one cannot and I don't know why.

```
import os, sys

os.system('IF EXIST C:\APC (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\APC)')

os.system('IF EXIST C:\APC\3d (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\APC\3d)')
```

If anyone knows the answer, pls let me know thanks!

Comment: try with raw prefix `r'IF EXIST C:\123 (echo1) else (mkdir C:\123)`. But you really should do this using `os` module in full python... `\1` is `\x01` illegal path name

Comment: are those the real paths?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just tried raw prefix but it still doesn't work?

Comment: are those the real paths or just an example?

Comment: If file paths contains space, quote them as so: `"C:\12 3\4 5 6\"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a directory if it does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist) That was the first hit on searching with my favorite www search engine for `Python create directory`. Please first give a simple search a try before asking and writing such awful code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's just an example actually...pls see my edit with real paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works by sheer luck:

```
os.system('IF EXIST C:\APC (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\APC)')
```

because the backslashes don't escape anything (`\A` isn't an escape sequence)

But just paste the second command in a python REPL and see:

```
>>> 'IF EXIST C:\APC\3d (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\APC\3d)'
'IF EXIST C:\\APC\x03d (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\\APC\x03d)'
```

backslashed digits are interpreted as the actual byte value... Using raw string prefix fixes that:

```
>>> r'IF EXIST C:\APC\3d (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\APC\3d)'
'IF EXIST C:\\APC\\3d (echo 1) else (mkdir C:\\APC\\3d)'
```

but don't call system commands to test & create dirs. Use pure python to do that:

```
import os

d = r"C:\APC\3d"
if os.path.exists(d):
    print("exists")
else:
    os.mkdir(d)
```

It's more readable, easier to debug, you benefit of python exceptions and makes your code more portable on other platforms (well, not with that hardcoded path of course)

Comment: I still got a question. When I run this code the first time, it works well and the program can run the other remaining codes. However, when I run the second time, it will return "Cannot create a file when that file already exist", and prevent the remaining codes from running. I tried to replace "print" with "pass", but it still doesn't work?

Comment: I'm puzzled, as `os.mkdir` is run only when `d` doesn't exist. Sure you're running this exact code? and the error originates from here?

Comment: Oh I didn't use `d` but the full directory. After I replace it with `d` then it works well! Why would this happen though? Thanks!