# Usage of bool_dir in python "from tools import bool_dir"

Tags: python

I am analyzing some old code in python and found this somewhere

```
from tools import bool_dir
```

I tried searching it but could not find anything. All I know is that maybe it is deprecated now and weblib is used instead of it. Can anyone please tell me the usage of this bool_dir.

Comment: Your question is severely lacking in context and/or relevant tags.

Comment: Sorry, I was just examining some old python code and didn't understood much of it and was just stuck at this part. I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some [likely code](https://github.com/kyodAI/QuoraQuestionPairMatching/blob/9006c16a8e41424a1e0ce98900e1ebf6d3e6f29c/tools.py#L12-L19) that matches your description.

The implementation from that is:

```
def bool_dir(path):
    """
    Check if directories exist else it create all the dirs

    """
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    return path
```

Note that this has a *race condition* so I'd suggest against using it.

If you're using python3 you can use:

```
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
```

for a race-free version.

For more information on the subject, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/812183).