# How to export file to another place with the same hierarchy in python?

Tags: python, image

I want to do the following thing:

Get all the images in a directory (include the images in subdirectory), do something with them (for example: resize), then export these images to another directory with the same hierarchy.

For example:

I want to get images from `input/flower/rose`, resize it and export to output, ask python to automatically create the hierarchy `flower/rose` inside output.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: first I used os.walk to get the hierarchy inside input, then use os.mkdir to creare the same hierarchy inside output, but it didnt work because there are some images with the same directory, which lead to the error "directory already exist"

Comment: Please edit your post to add your existing code and the complete error and traceback (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). FWIW, handling this kind of errors is not really complicated .

Answer (score 1):

[os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) will recreate the directory hierarchy if you use e.g.

```
os.makedirs("output/flower/rose")
```

Comment: I know it will, but actually in my task the images are stored in many folder, form a really complicated hierarchy, not only one like the example I mentioned. Also, the makedir will raise error if the directory already exist, so it is hard to use.

Comment: Regarding the "will raise an error", have a look at the top answers over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist