# Make a file directory with variables as names

Tags: python, pandas

I want a list of directories called `sim1`, `sim 2`, etc. created when a particular variable in my for loop is equal to 1, 2, etc.

I know that I have to use the `os` package (specifically the `os.makedirs()` function for directory creation) but have unfortunately not found the documentation pertaining specifically to this.

```
for n in np.arange(0,100):
    os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\adeet\\Desktop\\'/n)
```

I tried the above code- got the error - unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

and when I tried this-

```
for n in np.arange(0,100):
    os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\adeet\\Desktop\\n')
```

It made a folder named 'n' once and then gave me an error -[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Users\adeet\Desktop\n'

Comment: Have you implemented something? It would be easy to answer for people if you post the work done by you.

Comment: Check this post for directory operations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist

Comment: Edited to include my code

Comment: @Sam Saw that post before I posted the question here.. It doesn't answer my specific query

Comment: try os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\adeet\\Desktop\\'+str(n))

Comment: @Ben.T worked like a charm

Comment: @Ben.T any solution for the csv-
I have        
population_dfs[n].to_csv('C:\\Users\\adeet\\Desktop\\Epidemic Modelling\\Simulations\\Only Epidemic\\' +str(n))

Comment: @AVT not sure I understand what you ask, so maybe ask a new question (or edit this one as you don't have answer yet) but what I can see is that you don't have a file name in your `to_csv` so try something like `...Only Epidemic\\' +str(n) +'\\file_name.csv')`