# Problem with os.makedirs in Python not creating sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, operating-system

I have a script that runs hourly.

The output folder structure should be /todaysdate/hour/

So, at 00:00, the script will run & it should create both the todaysdate folder and a subfolder called 00.

At 01:00, the script will run - the todaysdate directory exists, so it should only create the subdirectory.

I've tried the below, but that doesn't work - how would I approach this?

```
file_path = 'Desktop/%s/%s' %(today_date, hour)
directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(os.getcwd())`? Is that where your Desktop is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that you want to create directories for each hour. So you don't need to get the dirname. This should do it:

```
file_path = 'Desktop/%s/%s' %(today_date, hour)
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.makedirs(file_path)
```

See docs for [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname).   This gives you the directory that contains `file_path`, e.g.

```
file_path = "Desktop/22-10-2018/00"
print(os.path.dirname(file_path))
>>> "Desktop/22-10-2018/"
```

Comment: Also see the `exists_ok` flag, for python >3.2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14364249/1643946. You can save yourself the os.path.exists test in this case