# Python 3.x Custom function chaining with an existing PATHLIB library Path() object

Tags: python, function, object, chaining, pathlib

I have defined a custom function based on `pathlib` module in my Python (3.x) script:

```
def mk_dir(self):
    self.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)

my_path = Path('./1/2/3/')
mk_dir(my_path)
```

as a shorthand to create a new directory with `pathlib.Path.mkdir()` function.

This function will create any missing parents of the given path (`parents=True`) and will not raise an error if the directory already exists (`exist_ok=True`).

However, I would like to modify my function so it would operate as a chained function, i.e., `my_path.mk_dir()`; instead of the traditional method by passing a variable, i.e., `mk_dir(my_path)`.

I tried it the following way:

```
from pathlib import Path

class Path():
    def mk_dir(self):
        self.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)
        return self

my_path = Path('./1/2/3/')
my_path.mk_dir()
```

but the best I am getting is this error:

```
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'mk_dir'
```

How can one achieve this without changing the module source file itself?

And I am uncertain about these questions:

1. Does `class` need to be defined?
2. Does the function need to return anything?
3. And, is it a better practice to check first if the directory exists by `if not my_path.is_dir(): ...` or it is "okay" to use the `exist_ok=True` attribute?

   - I could not conclude this myself, but a related question is here:
   - [How can I safely create a nested directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory-in-python/46831916#46831916)

Comment: If you want to override a method, you need to define a subclass. Your `Path` class has nothing to do with `pathlib.Path`, and while it's technically possible, you don't want to monkey patch `pathlib.Path` to change how its `mkdir` function works.

Comment: However, I don't recommend overriding a method in a way that changes the signature. Define a new method that wraps `mkdir` with your desired arguments.

Comment: Also, this isn't "function chaining"; it's just method invocation.