# Python: open function fails to open a new file with append

Tags: python, ansible

I am writing a custom `ansible` module.

Here is how it is invoked:

```
  - name: mymodule.yml -> Run mymodule
    mymodule:
      test_file: "{{ item }}"
      env_file: "{{ environment_file.stdout }}"
      out_dir: "{{ nginx_folder }}/{{ rv_dir_name.stdout }}"
      base_url: "{{ results_base_url }}"
    become: yes
```

At some point in time, within the module, the following python commands are invoked:

```
# use file for the stderr descriptor of the subprocess.call
try:
    # os.mkdir(_out_dir, 0755 )
    ferr = open('std_err.log', 'w')
    # fout = open('std_out.log', 'w')   
    fout = open(_out_dir + "/" + 'std_out.log', 'a')
except Exception as exc:
    module.fail_json(msg="Hello: " + str(exc))
# fout = open('std_out.log', 'a')
```

The following line gives this error when I execute the module:

> "msg": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/html/newman-tests/2019-03-25_09:34:04/std_out.log'",

Why does it fail to create / open the file, despite the fact that:

a) the module is called with `become: yes`

b) `open` is called with `a` that should create the file if it doesn't exist?

**edit**: the folder **does** exist because calling this in advance

```
os.mkdir(_out_dir, 0755 )
```

Fails with `directory exists`

What is more, a few lines below in my module I am calling this:

```
rc = call(["newman", "run", _test_file, "-k", "-e", _env_file, "-r", "htmlextra,cli", "--reporter-html-report", "--reporter-htmlextra-export", _output], stderr=ferr)
```

Where

```
_output = _out_dir + "/" + _report_fname
```

i.e. `_out_dir` is the same dir where the above `open` fails

(and this works OK)

Comment: Uhm, Try with  `a+`

Comment: Does the folder `_out_dir` exist already, or are you expecting it to be created with this call to `open`?

Comment: Example at [How can I safely create a nested directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/5358968)

Comment: check my __edit__  on the initial question;

Comment: In a clean interpreter I have no issue creating and writing to a new file with `if not os.path.exists(_out_dir): os.mkdir(_out_dir)` and `open(_out_dir + "/" + 'test.txt', 'a')` - I'm not sure about the effect of your `call`.

Comment: Did you try adding the `if not os.path.exists [...]` before your open? You said that you've run another line before, so this line shouldn't run, but it rules out some potential issues.

Comment: Yes I went ahead with your suggestion and it solved the problem! I can't understand why though; in any case if you post the answer I will accept it;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I safely create a nested directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory-in-python)

Comment: Just adding this here: `--reporter-html-report` that means nothing, in the context of the reporter that you are using. Not part of what you're asking but just an fyi :)

Answer (score 1):

`a+` file is created if it does not exist. The initial file position for reading is at the begining of the file, but output is appended to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

as mention above, or use mode `'x'` which create a new file and open it for writing