# How do I open a file in a specific directory?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```py
import os
...
    savepath = "/home/myname/Documents/programfolder/vanities/"
    #ctx.author.id is from the discord.py module, not relevant to question.
    userFile = os.path.join(savepath, str(ctx.author.id) + ".txt")
    ...
    try:
            vanity = open(userFile, "r")
            vanity = vanity.read()
            server = get_guild(myserverid)
            vanityrole = server.get_role(vanity)
            vanityrole = role.edit(name = str(rolename), colour = int(hexcolour))
    except FileNotFoundError:
            vanity = open(userFile, "w")
            vanityrole = role_create(name = str(rolename), colour = int(hexcolour))
            vanity = vanity.write(str(vanityrole.id))
            pass
```

When I run this, I receive an error

```
Ignoring exception in command vanity:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bot.py", line 27, in vanity
    vanity = open(userFile, "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/myname/Documents/programfolder/vanities/myid.txt'
```

Why does the try:
except FileNotFoundError:
not work?
I tried it with except IOError and OSError and neither worked.
The error also occurs with open(userFile, "w").
For reference, my program runs in /home/myname/Documents/programfolder/

Comment: @Chrispresso How would that help the understand why the `except FileNotFoundError:` clause isn't executing as expected?

Comment: The `pass` on the last line looks rather odd.

Comment: @Chrispresso still get the same errors.

Comment: Remove `try` and the entire `except` block. Run your code. Report what it says.

Comment: It's really confusing the way you keep using the `vanity` variable for different things. Avoid reusing the same variable like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `savepath` exists.

- If the directory doesn't exist, the error you encountered always happens.

  - Refer to [How can I safely create a nested directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory)
- Append mode can handle both write and read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

  - It'll create the file (not directory) *if* the directory exists
  - Otherwise, if no such directory, same idea, "No such file or directory"

The `with` clause takes care of closing resources, in most cases. You can wrap something like this in a try/catch, or check first if the directory doesn't exist (first link above) and then create if needed.

```py
# handle directory existence first, here
...
with open(userFile, 'a+') as fp:
    fp.seek(0)
    contents = fp.read()
    # handle contents if found, here
    if not contents:
        newContents = ...
        fp.write(newContents)
```