# Python create dirs recursivly

Tags: python, directory

How to create directories with python module `os` like

```
$ mkdir -p /some_non_exsitance_path/path
```

Comment: already answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely create a nested directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory)

Answer (score -1):

There is a method in the `os` module that allows you to create multiple folders

```
os.makedirs(r'/some_non_exsitance_path/path')
```