# Making new directory with python os

Tags: python, python-os

I'm python beginner. I wanted to make 50 directories in my laptop with python. IDK what to do plz help

```
import os
from os.path import *

home = expanduser('~')

dl_path = home + '\\Downloads'

def main():
    if not os.path.exist(dl_path):
        print("path does'nt exist")
        os.makedirs(dl_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 1
    while a<= 50:
        main()
        a += 1
```

This is my code which doesn't work :(
I don't know if it's given an error but here it is:
[image]

Comment: Please! add what error you are getting?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: aren't you just creating the same directory 50 times? also you should look into basic python for loops, this is not how you write a loop in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely create a nested directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/6045800)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of '+' it is better to use `os.path.join` - it works with filenames in a smarter way. Also, you have forgotten to elaborate on the `else` statement, when you do the actual job instead of throwing an exception. Also, you need a new name for each new directory - they can't all have the same name. Also, do you want nested directories or directories at the same level?

This makes directories at the same level.

```
import os
from os.path import *

home = expanduser('~')

dl_path = os.path.join(home, 'Downloads')

def main():
    if not os.path.exist(dl_path):
        print("path does'nt exist")
    else:
        a = 1
        while a <= 50:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(dl_path, str(a)))
            a += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This makes nested directories:

```
import os
from os.path import *

home = expanduser('~')

dl_path = home

def main():
    if not os.path.exist(dl_path):
        print("path does'nt exist")
    else:
        a = 1
        while a <= 50:
            dl_path = os.makedirs(os.path.join(dl_path, 'Downloads'))
            a += 1
        os.makedirs(dl_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I would suggest to use for loop for known number of iterations: https://support.khanacademy.org/hc/en-us/articles/203327020-When-do-I-use-a-for-loop-and-when-do-I-use-a-while-loop-in-the-JavaScript-challenges-

Comment: yes, agree, it is better in this case.