# I'm getting a "FileNotFoundError" even though I'm *making* a file

Tags: python, file-handling, file-not-found

I'm trying to make a directory with a file in it

```py
# lines 1-5
import logging, os

unix_doc_loc = '~\\byeStore'
win32_doc_loc = 'C:\\byeStore'

[...]
# line 108
class Store():
[...]
# lines 132-148
    def CacheCatalogue():
        import sys, os, time, platform, json
        byelogs.debug('sys, os and time were imported')
        # catalogue = Store.GetCatalogue() # commented out as this isn't functional yet
        catalogue = '{"lastUpdated": 1}'
        catalogue = json.loads(catalogue)
        byelogs.info('Catalogue recieved.')
        byelogs.debug(catalogue)
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            byelogs.info('Detected Windows ({}). Using "C:\\byeStore\\"...'.format(sys.platform)) # line 142 - the troublesome line
            catcache = open('C:\\byeStore\\catalogue-cache.json', 'wt')
            byelogs.debug('Opened catcache')
        if catalogue['lastUpdated'] >= catcache['lastUpdated']:
            byelogs.info('Catalouge in cache is old. Updating...')
            catcache.write(catalogue)
            byelogs.info('Updated.')
```

Here's my terminal output

```
Z:\ByeStore\ByeStoreLibs>featuretest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\ByeStore\ByeStoreLibs\featuretest.py", line 5, in <module>
    byestore.Store.CacheCatalogue()
  File "Z:\ByeStore\ByeStoreLibs\src\byestore\__init__.py", line 142, in CacheCatalogue
    catcache = open('C:\\byeStore\\catalogue-cache.json', 'wt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\byeStore\\catalogue-cache.json'

Z:\ByeStore\ByeStoreLibs>
```

I remember that the `'wt'` part in `open(file, 'wt')` *makes* files. I even tried using `"x"`, but that just didn't work, either. I just *can't* make the files for some reason.

My files are [on GitHub, if you want the full source](https://github.com/ByeStore/ByeStoreLibs/blob/main/src/byestore/__init__.py).

Comment: The `'w'` mode creates *files*, but not *directories*... Are you sure the full path up-to the file actually exists?

Comment: I tried `os.mkdir()` as well, forgot to mention that

Comment: Again, `mkdir` only creates the directory, i.e. the *last part* of the path. You need `mkdirs` to make sure it creates the *whole* path

Comment: See [How can I safely create a nested directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

d = "C:\\byeStore\\"
Path(d).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
open(d + "catalogue-cache.json", 'w+')
```

Couple things here:

1. Create the directory first.
2. `'w'` is used for creating the file if it does not exist, not `'t'`.

Comment: `t` marks it as text, just for making sure that's clear to the interpreter, even though it's not necessary I use it just in case.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what the params parents=True and exist_ok=True mean?

Comment: parents=True creates the parent directories, exist_ok=True means it doesn't error if it already exists