# How to automatically create folders in python?

Tags: python, automation, scheduling

I want to create a folder for current year. Inside current year folder, there will be a folder for current month, and inside current month folder each day a current date folder will continue to be created. That's how as time passes, new month folders and year folders would continue to be created.

I want to automate this whole folder creation. How can I do so?

Much thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at the *os* module. You'll find it very useful. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely create a nested directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory-in-python)

Comment: I recommend using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) over os as it provides a more modern way of dealing with filesystem operations