# Checking folder and if it doesn't exist create it

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I am quite new to python so I need some help. I would like to create a code that checks if a folder with a given name is created, if not, it creates it, if it exists, goes to it and in it checks if there is another folder with a given name, if not, it creates it. In my code I don't know how to go to folder that already exist or has just been created and repeat IF.

```
import os


MYDIR = ("test")
CHECK_FOLDER = os.path.isdir(MYDIR)


if not CHECK_FOLDER:
    os.makedirs(MYDIR)
    print("created folder : ", MYDIR)

else:
    print(MYDIR, "folder already exists.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely create a nested directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to create a folder inside a second folder or check the existence of them you can use builtin `os` library:

```
import os

PATH = 'folder_1/folder_2'
if not os.path.exists(PATH):
    os.makedirs(PATH)
```

`os.makedirs()` create all folders in the PATH if they does not exist.

Answer (score 13):

os has an inbuilt method for this, you can simply do: `os.makedirs("dir", exist_ok=True)`. This will basically create a folder if it does not exist and do nothing if the folder already exists.

```
import os

PATH = 'folder_1/folder_2'
os.makedirs(PATH, exist_ok=True)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
directory0="directory0"
## If folder doesn't exists, create it ##
if not os.path.isdir(directory0):
    os.mkdir(directory0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use os import or pathlib to manage your path (example: to know if your path is a dir, if exist ...)

The os import have OS dependent features, so I recommend to use pathlib.

If you check on google you will find lot of example like:

https://www.guru99.com/python-check-if-file-exists.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-directory-in-python/