# Django - export one txt file per row to local drive

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck with this as I can't find any relevant tutorials online. I would like to

1. export all of the data in a model to the txt file format {actually xml but I think that's besides the point}
2. where each row in the model is a seperate file
3. and saved to a relative local path to the database
4. with the folder and filenames for each being derived from two fields in the model
5. I also need these to replace any existing files of the same name

Where would I start? All I can do currently is export a txt file with all records together as a downloadable attachment.

This is what the code would like if I were presenting it as a HTML page, however of course the filename and folder fields are not referenced.

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;
&lt;movie&gt;
  &lt;plot /&gt;
  &lt;outline /&gt;
  &lt;title&gt;{{ misc.title }}&lt;/title&gt;
  &lt;release date&gt;{{ misc.d_released }}&lt;/release date&gt;

  &lt;/fileinfo&gt;
&lt;/movie&gt;
```

Here are the fields

```
class misc(models.Model):
d_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=250)
folder = models.ForeignKey(folder, default="1", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='', blank=True, null=True)
d_released = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', blank=True, null=True)
description = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-id', )
```

Comment: Well the options I see is either to use Django's views or ignore Django and connect to database via python. The former is what I'm asking for help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't need Django for this task (maybe).

#### UPD:

Use CSV!
Your Excel could export data into a `.csv` file - this is a very simple format and very easy to start with Python.

Place your `.csv` near you python script otherwise provide a full path to the file:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

So check that you can read the data of your rows. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Next, let's make a handler for your rows:

Here you can use XML builder but this is not a quick way.
Let's make something like a text template and replace the needed macros with your row's values as you defined in the beginning.

```
f`text {param}`
```

Finally, how to write this to the filesystem? Easy!

First, how to create a dir or nested dirs? A good thread here:

[How can I safely create a nested directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory)

So create a needed dir and then you can concatenate dir + needed filename to create a file:

```
with open("full_path_to_future_file.xml", "w") as f:
   f.write(rendered_xml_as_text)
```

All these stuff you can do when iterating in your
`for row in reader:` cycle, of course.

Call your script like `python script.py` and task solved!

###### Old answer:

Can you clarify once again all the data's pipeline with needed artifacts?
Like:

1. I have such row(s) in Excel...(example)
2. I want to read each row and ...
3. I want to process each row like this...
4. I want to store this into... that will be used for ...