# Create a directory, only if it doesn't exist using python os.mkdir()

Tags: python, operating-system, mkdir

We can create a directory, only if it does not exist using

`mkdir -p ./my_directory/`

How can we achieve the same using `os.mkdir()` in python?
`os.mkdir("./my_directory/")` fails if `./my_directory/` already exists and `os.mkdir(" -p ./my_directory/")` is not working.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-directory-possibly-including-intermediate-directories/14364249#14364249

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely create a directory (possibly including intermediate directories)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-directory-possibly-including-intermediate-directories)

Comment: Just do like ```os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)```. It's the best solution currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
#python program to check if a directory exists
import os
path = "pythonprog"

# Check whether the specified path exists or not
isExist = os.path.exists(path)
if not isExist:
    # Create a new directory because it does not exist
       os.makedirs(path)
       print("The new directory is created!")
```